# Automata regular expression {0+1}*

Tags: regex, automata

I'm new in Automata concept AND In some papers I found `{0,1}*` .

1. Is it same as `(0+1)*`
2. Also can we generate 101 from the `(0+1)*`
3. can we generate 101 from the `{0,1}*`
        if 1) answer is NO

PLEASE any one help me to solve this confusion..

Comment: could you please explain why 1 get NO  @WhileTrueSleep

Answer (score 4):

**If all of them are found in computer science paper and computational theory books**, then yes, they are likely the same.

- In the notation `{0,1}*`, set notation `{0,1}` is used to denote "0 or 1".
- Alternatively, `+` is also used to denote alternation ([JFLAP](http://www.jflap.org/), for example). So `(0+1)` can also mean "0 or 1".
- `|` is also used to denote alternation `(0|1)` in theoretical computer science context. This is also the syntax for alternation in many regex engines.

The Kleene star `*` is, having the same notation in both theoretical regular expression (books, paper) and practical regex library, denotes repetition of 0 or more times of the preceding atom.

Since they mean "(0 or 1) repeated 0 or more times", both of them can generate the language `101`.

As @Bergi mentioned in the comment, you should take a step back when you see both syntax being used in the same book/paper. For example, @paarandika noted that `+` can actually means "repeat once or more times" in book/paper if it is in superscript.

Comment: (0+1)* means {e,0,1,001,01,1111}   
 (0|1)* is for same?

Comment: @TostackOverlow: `(0|1)` is the common syntax for alternation in regex library. I don't know whether it is used in paper or not, but if you see it, it is likely that it also has the same meaning as the other 2.

Comment: + 1, but notice that if they are found in the *same* paper or book, then they likely mean different things.